# Self join combined with other joins is not working

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I cannot perform a query formed by this set of tables:

**Table A**: id, name, parent_id, tableB_id

**Table B**: id

**Table C**: id, tableB_id, english_name, french_name

Let's suppose that I have the next data in those Tables:

**Table A**:

| name | parent_id | tableB_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | Null | 1 |
| Second | 1 | Null |
| Third | Null | 2 |

**Table C**:

| tableB_id | english_name | french_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | watermelon | pastèque |
| 2 | lemon | citron |
| 3 | apple | pomme |

I have to create a query joining:

**Table A**, with hierarchy dependencies, so, a row can be parent of another.
I have to **join the table with itself**, fine up to here (I already have this query done)

Now I need to **join** the previous query **with another table**, which it is linked via foreign key, but not only this, because I need the translated name of the linked row, and **the translations are written in another table**

In the end I have to link:

- Table A with itself.
- Table A with Table B to obtain the id.
- Table B with Table C (translation table) to obtain the translated name of the Table B

All the attributes linked with the table A **accept Null** values, so I need to **Left Join** to include them.

I am trying to do this query, but I'm not finding a way, currently I have the first query which is this:

```
alias = aliased(TableA)
db.session.query(TableA.name, alias.name).join(TableA.parent.of_type(alias), isouter=True)
```

I have tried regular joins and subqueries, but, the first method it´s not working, and the second one, "looks like" it is working but sends a massive amount of duplicate rows.

**Expected result**:
In the end, I expect to have a query that returns:

| name | parent_name | english_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | Null | watermelon |
| Second | First | Null |
| Third | Null | lemon |

Comment: The description is not clear enough. Provide a sample - CREATE TABLE for both tables, INSERT INTO with some sample data (3-5 rows each) and desired output for this data with detailed explanations. *Table A, with hierarchy dependencies, so, a row can be parent of another.* Does there exists only 2 nesting levels? or there are more levels?

Comment: Without overly reading the actual issue, I'd suggest look if it's possible to use the `selectinload` style, where instead of joining everything at once, you do the first query, then something like `select(TableC).where(expr.in_(results_from_first_query))`.